# How to list dependecies cabal calculates

Tags: haskell, dependencies, versioning, cabal

Is there a way to list the dependencies cabal-install calculates, without installing them? Maybe in a tree, or vine-like format? I'm trying to install an old package, and one of its dependencies is trying to use a package incompatible with my system (process-1.1.0.2, and I'm on GHC-7.8.3). Is there a simple way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do it: `cabal install --dry-run <package-name>`